# How to fetch data from one table to another using the logged user session id

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to MySQL database.In my admin panel. when I add subcategory the main category will show in drop down with the logged in user category. Right now in my category drop down show all user category data. I want to display the only logged user category from database.but I didn't get what to do. please anyone know help me.

Below I share my code

```
 <div class="form-group">     
    <select class="form-control" name="input_cat" id="input_cat" onchange="category_select(this)">
                            <?php
                                    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM category";
                                    /* execute multi query */
                                    if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $query1)) {
                                        do {
                                            echo '<option value=-1>select Category</option>';
                                            /* store first result set */
                                            if ($resulttest = mysqli_store_result($conn)) {
                                                while ($test = mysqli_fetch_row($resulttest)) {

                                                    echo "<option value=" . $test[0] .">". $test[1].
                                                    "</option>";
                                                }
                                            }

                                        } while (mysqli_next_result($conn));
                                    }
                                    ?>
                        </select>     
               <input type="hidden" name="catid" id="catidval" value="">                              
    </div>
     below my query and database connection.

<?php
 require 'dbconfig.php';
  if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
  session_start();     

 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$venderID=$_SESSION['vid'];
$subcategory = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['subcategory']);
$catid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['catid']);
$item_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['item_type']);
$price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['price']);

 $sql = "INSERT INTO item 
(vendor_id,item_name,category_id,item_type,item_rate) VALUES 
('$venderID','$subcategory','$catid','$item_type','$price');";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


if ($result) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Sub-category Added 
Successfully.");</script>'; }
else
    {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Oops! some error.");</script>';
     }
}
     ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my bug by using the query ...

```
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE vendor_id = ".$venderID;
```